# Is there a way to make a password into stars

Tags: python, passwords

I am making a password checker but I want it to print out the passcode but in *.
My code is:
username = input("What is your name?")
password = input("What is your password?")

```
password_length = len(password)

print(f'{username}, your password, {password}, is {password_length} letters long')
```

Comment: Does `"*"*password_length` get you what you want?  Or are you trying to also obscure the password during the `input()` call?

Comment: The * times the length of the password works.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f'{username}, your password, {"*" * password_length}, is {password_length} letters long')
```

Comment: Are you saying that I do * times the length of the password?

Comment: The multiplication operator is `*`, not `x`.